# Adding data to map and not saving it on local path using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layer-package

Using ArcGIS Pro, I have loaded an APRX file that is located on a network share.

I added a layer to the map using **Add Data**.  The layer is named "USA_Detailed_Water_Bodies.lpk".

The added layer is stored locally in C:\Users\user\Documents\ArcGIS\Packages\USA_Detailed_Water_Bodies_41CAC1A1-63B9-4999-9149-7A6CB9942149\v104\dtl_wat.gdb

How can the layer be added to the map and stored with the map on the network share in order for other users to view the Water Bodies layer when the APRX file is loaded on another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, a *.lpk is a layer package file. It is similar to a Zip / Compressed file containing the features for use in ArcMap / ArcGIS Pro.

By default it will extract to the "C:\Users\user\Documents\ArcGIS\Packages" on any machine.

Thus in order to get this available to all, you will need to copy the data out of this folder, to a location available to all on the network share.

Then you can add the layer from that location to you APRX and save it. As long as the data is being read from the network, then everyone on the network should be able to see it.

To copy data, I would suggest using the Catalog window (located within ArcMap) or exporting it out to the correct location - right-clicking the file and choosing Data and then Export Features and the path to export to. As per @Polygeo's comment, there are also Geoprocessing Tools allowing to copy data between locations.

Answer (score 2):

Any time that you can create a project where all of the project’s resources are within the folder of that project (and therefore on the same drive), the project will be easy to move to a new location (by simply copying the project folder), and if all data is local such a project is likely to perform at its best.

When you create a project where some of the project’s resources are outside the folder of that project (perhaps on shared drives) and you want to move it somewhere that cannot see those resources in the same locations, you will need to [project package](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/overview/project-package.htm) them and make sure to check the **Share outside of organization** option so that those resources get copied into the package.

Alternatively/additionally, you may move any data source to where you want it to be located, and then manually set the data source to the new location for any layers that need to reference it.